# Обработчик радиокликов для выбора фигуры

Tags: c#, winforms, radiobutton

Имеется код для приложения на WinForms

```
// обработчик радиокликов для выбора фигуры
private void radioGroup_CheckedChanged_Figures(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string text=(sender as Radiobutton)?.Text; // тут приведение отправителя к элементу типа RadioButton, но непонятен синтаксис ?Техт - что это такое?
    Figure=text;
```

Comment: `Text` - это свойство контрола `RadioBitton` [Члены класса (Руководство по программированию на C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members)

Comment: `?.` - это [Null-conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)